# Grouping and counting in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to group all words occurring in a row, count their freq-values and sort by counts result. It has to be done in sql only. Here's an example:

I have the following table:

```
word | freq
-----------
car  | 5
cake | 2
car  | 4
```

and want to get this result:

```
word | freq
-----------
car  | 9
cake | 2
```

Comment: RTFM? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

You can group by word which later be summed according to group made....

```
  SELECT word,SUM(freq) AS freq FROM tblName GROUP BY word
```

When you have to order the word according to freq, you can use ORDER BY in following way:

```
SELECT word,SUM(freq) AS freq FROM tblName GROUP BY word ORDER BY freq DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT word, SUM(freq) AS freq FROM yourTable GROUP BY word ORDER BY freq DESC;
```